# Azure Python SDK Credential Refresh

Tags: python, azure

I'm using the `azure python sdk` to programmatically connect to azure services via `linux`.

I can login successfully via `az('login')`

```
login found
```

However, when I try to create credentials and get a token, I get an error that my grant is expired:

```
creds = DefaultAzureCredential()
token = creds.get_token('https://database.windows.net/.default')

VisuaLStudioCodeCredential.get_token failed: Azure Active Directory error ' (invalid_grant) AADSTS50173: The provided grant has expired due to it being revoked, a fresh auth token is needed. The user might have changed or reset their password. The grant was issued on '2021-11-04T15:21:38,19517642' and the TokensValidFrom date (before which tokens are not valid) for this user is '2022-01-0819:52:17.0000000z'
```

How do I refresh this? I tried using `az('account clear')`, then `az('login')` but I get the same result. Is there a method specific for `DefaultAzureCredential` to get a refreshed token?

Comment: Have you tried signing out in VS Code and sign in again. Other alternative would be to exclude VS Code credentials from the list of credentials in DefaultAzureCredential so that it can use Azure CLI credentials.

Comment: @GauravMantri Logging out / logging in didn't work. Excluding VScode from the DefaultAzureCredential did work. If you want to post it, I'll accept the answer. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DefaultAzureCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python) class tries to acquire a token using multiple methods in a particular order and VS Code logged in user has a higher precedence than Azure CLI logged in user.

When you use `az login`, you are logging in using Azure CLI and it seems you are already logged in into VS Code using some other credentials which does not have proper permissions and this is why you are getting this error.

To fix this issue, you can exclude VS Code credentials to be considered by setting `exclude_visual_studio_code_credential` to `true`. So your code would be something like:

```
creds = DefaultAzureCredential(exclude_visual_studio_code_credential=true)
```

That way DefaultAzureCredential will not take your VS Code credentials to acquire the token.